# google app engine memcached Login

Tags: php, google-app-engine, authentication, memcached

I have been building this website using the GAE and designed it around a memcached login system (based on a small google search saying memcached is better than session).

it seems that memcached stores its variables globally. So now when i login on one computer if i go to another computer it shows as logged in.

```
$user = new Memcached();

//inputs and database query omitted
  //$row is an array with user's data 
$user->setMulti(['id' => $row['userID'], 'email' => $row['email'], 'password' => $row['password'], 'fname' => $row['fName'], 'lname'=>$row['lName'], 'type'=>$row['userType']], 3000);
```

on every other page I retrieve login data like this

```
$user = new Memcached();
$id=$user->get('id');
$email=$user->get('email');
$fname=$user->get('fname');
$lname=$user->get('lname');
$type=$user->get('type');
```

is there a way to prevent these logins from being global? or do i have to change everything to session?

Answer (score 1):

Memcache is shared by all instances and all requests in each instance. Besides, Memcache may be cleared at any time. Your users will not appreciate being thrown out of your app randomly. Memcache is not suitable for login purposes.

You need to use sessions. Each session is linked to one user.

In Java runtime, by the way, sessions are stored in Memcache, and they are also backed by the Datastore. I don't see it in PHP runtime documentation, but it's very likely the implementation is the same.

Answer (score 0):

The memcache behaviour is expected - all instances share the same [memcache service](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/memcache/):

> **Note:** The cache is global and is shared across the application's
>   frontend, backend, and all of its modules/versions.

Indeed, if you want per-user login you have to use a session service.